# What does the FS_REQUIRES_DEV flag do in Linux filesystems?

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, ext2

I was reading the source for `ext2fs` where the filesystem is registered with the FS_REQUIRES_DEV flag in [fs/ext2/super.c](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/fs/ext2/super.c#L1558). Both [fs.h](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L2018) and the kernel documentation don't say anything else about this flag.

I also tried to look up how the VFS uses of this flag but no other uses show up apart what appears to be printing a list of filesystems (in [fs/filesystem.c](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/fs/filesystems.c#L214)).

What does this flag represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag means that every instance of given filesystem uses underlying *block device*, where filesystem content is stored.

There are filesystems, which do not use block device. Among them "in-memory" filesystems, like `sysfs`, `debugfs`. Also, client part of network filesystems (e.g., `nfs`) doesn't need block device.